# Swift: How to remove a view from VC?

Tags: ios, swift

I currently have an app where when a user taps a button a view is added to the VC which displays a video (taken by user). a button is also added to the view, when a user press it should remove the view with everything that came with it.

**How can I remove the view?**

Currently I have tried:

```
  self.view.superview?.removeFromSuperview()
```

Which does not work.

Bellow is all relevant code:

```
  func newViewVideoPlayback(videoURL: URL!) {

    let newView = UIImageView(frame: camPreview.bounds)
    self.view.superview?.addSubview(newView)

    //cancelButton create dec 1
    let cancelButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 589, width: 145, height: 78))
    cancelButton.setTitle("Cancel", for: .normal)
    cancelButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAction), for: .touchUpInside)
    cancelButton.setTitleColor(.red, for: .normal)
    cancelButton.layer.cornerRadius = 8
    cancelButton.backgroundColor = .white

    self.view.superview?.addSubview(cancelButton) //maybe do newView, then subview

    playerItem1 = AVPlayerItem(url: videoURL as URL)
    playerQueue = AVQueuePlayer(playerItem: playerItem1)
    playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: playerQueue)
    playerLooper = AVPlayerLooper(player: playerQueue, templateItem: playerItem1)

    playerLayer.frame = newView.bounds //shud it be view.bounds
    playerLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill
    newView.layoutIfNeeded() //same as other view comment

    newView.layer.insertSublayer(playerLayer, at: 0)

    //newView.superview?.bringSubview(toFront: newView)
    self.playerQueue?.play()

}
```

**Button**:

```
    @objc func buttonAction(sender: UIButton!) {
    print("Button tapped")
    //for cancelButon
    //playerQueue = nil
    self.view.superview?.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

The func is called in a method which adds the video URL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you probably want to do is remove `newView`, not `view`'s `superview` from the ViewController.

Create a global variable for `newView`:

```
class YourViewController: UIViewController {

    var newView: UIImageView?
    ...
```

...then assign `newView` like this:

```
func newViewVideoPlayback(videoURL: URL!) {

    newView = UIImageView(frame: camPreview.bounds)
    ...
```

...and when you need to remove this view call just this:

```
newView?.removeFromSuperview()
```

Your button action should look like this:

```
@objc func buttonAction(sender: UIButton!) {
    print("Button tapped")
    //for cancelButon
    //playerQueue = nil
    newView?.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

Comment: I accepted your answer cuz it answerd teh question. However I am wondering if this is teh best/fastest way to preview a video taken in app. For me it is a littler buggy and not nessasarily fast. I hypothesized that snapchat may do somthing like this to make there video so fast but am unsure. Do they maby use a new VC? programaticaly added?